# Grouping column data

Tags: excel

Just wondering if there is a way to group the same value from a column to another column? Example as below, all the duplicates are consolidated into one

[image]

Hope to get a response soon and Merry Christmas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous methods. An array formula is one; Advanced Filter, VBA with a scripting dictionary, copy and paste then remove duplicates are among others.

Here's an array formula. Put it in C2, finish with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (instead of just enter) and fill down until you start returning #N/A errors..

```
=INDEX(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A)), MATCH(0, COUNTIF(C$1:C1, A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A))), 0))
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you for your prompt response!